# Make Single User ALL camera actions

Tags: camera, linked-data

**Make Single User ALL camera actions**

I need to copy, in a bunch of pre existing cameras, animations data ,rotation,location and lens (Focal...), between several cameras and make this animations data as single user for some cameras

exemple:  I select two cameras ( A & B) taking care that the cameras (A) with animation data is active and i run this:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='ANIMATION')

bpy.context.object.select_set(state = False) 

bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=False, obdata=True, material=False, animation=True)
```

so i link animation data from active camera (A) to selected  (B) with the folowing command:

```
bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='ANIMATION')
```

i deselect camera (A):

```
 bpy.context.object.select_set(state = False)
```

and i make camera Action of camera (B) as single user:

```
 bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=False, obdata=True, material=False, animation=True)
```

But only Object Camera  Action (Rotation & Location...) are modified as single user. Action linked to Object data Camera (lens animation)  are always linked

i can perform this action in outliner

[image]

but how to do this with python ?